# Test query against documents in Elasticsearch without storing them in index

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-percolate

I have a set of documents that are not stored in any Elasticsearch index (and I don't want to) that I want to test against an Elasticsearch query. Basically I want to see how the Elasticsearch analyser would respond to an arbitrary query against arbitrary documents, without creating indexes.

I've been looking at the [Explain](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html) API, the [Analyze](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) API. [Percolate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-percolate-query.html) kinda does what I'm looking for but it's completely unnecessary for my case to store the query in an index. The flow with percolate I've been testing is to:

1. user initiates query
2. store query in percolate index with randomly generated unique ID
3. run percolate query with `documents: []` array
4. remove query in percolate index with ID from 2

It's an ad-hoc query so it does not need to be stored, and I'm running into race conditions where the query stored in step 2 only returns results reliably if I put a `sleep 1` before running the `percolate` query.

Basically, the API I'm looking for would look something like this:

```
GET /_test_query
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string": {
       "query": "james blunt",
       "fields": ["title", "content"]
    }
  },
  "documents": [{
     "id": "bbb",
     "title": "James Blunt tweets",
     "content": "That he loves Ibiza"
  }, {
    "id": "aaa",
    "title": "Ed Sheeran tweets",
    "content": "That he loves music"
  }]
}
```

With a response similar to a regular search query:

```
{ "hits": { "hits": [{ _id: "bbb"}] } }
// etc
```

Is this possible in Elasticsearch, or is Percolate the only way?

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch doesn't have an api like that, but it's a neat idea and it might be worth raising a feature request

index the documents, or use percolate